# Office 365 web services

Tags: web-services, office365

I want to connect to the Office 365 web service for my organisation, however when I browse to the web service address and log in, the page just returns blank.

Any clever people here who know what I am missing?

I'm using this format: `"https://" + "Server name" + "/EWS/Exchange.amsx"`

Comment: Please close this question. I figured it out. Like a doughnut I was using "amsx" as opposed to "asmx".

Answer (score 1):

To get the right endpoint to talk to, you use the Discovery Service API. This will return the URL for your organization’s endpoint. The O365 endpoint can change (don’t use hardcoded URL’s in your code), by using the Discovery Service API you always have the right URL you need.

**Common endpoint discovery tasks using the Discovery Service API**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/discover-service-endpoints